# Manifest files in google adon

Tags: google-apps-script, manifest.json

I have two manifest files for two adons i need to merge it how do i do that?.
I have used Calendar, to-do list, Translator  Google script then all have different dependency files(json) how do i merge them together so that they are in one plugin

```
{
  "timeZone": "Africa/Nairobi",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ],
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "gmail": {
    "name": "CoreBOS",
    "logoUrl": "https://corebos.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/logo.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {},
      "onTriggerFunction": "addonInit"
    }],
    "primaryColor": "#FEB117",
    "secondaryColor": "#1F365C"
  }
}
```

Comment: The Google Translate examples for add-ons show usage in Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides.  The documentation shows how to use the same code for multiple different types of Google documents.  They way that you merge your separate add-ons together is by configuring the manifest according to the documentation.  And if you have duplicate code, eliminate the duplicate code.  You will need to make the effort to study the documentation and attempt to create the manifest yourself.  If you create a new manifest, and have a specific problem, then ask about the specific problem.

Comment: I have been trying to merge the files without success.

Comment: The information provided is not sufficient to determine the reason for the lack of success.  We do not know the content of the two manifest files, or the code contained in the project files.  But even if you posted the entire contents of both project files, your question would still be considered "off topic"  because it is to broad.  To provide a working answer, someone would need to do all the work for you, or provide a complete tutorial of how to combine the two projects.  You are asking too much.